# Fill a column with a coordinate X or Y with PyQgis

Tags: python, pyqgis

I've created a new field on my layer (points vector) named `Coord_X`, and want to fill it with the coordinate of all features. 
I'm trying this way, but something is not right:

```
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    x = geom.asPoint().x()

for f in x:
    new_values = {layer.fieldNameIndex('Coord_X') : x}
    provider.changeAttributeValues({x.index(f):new_values})
```

Comment: Tip: If you need to 1) fill columns with coordinates and 2) keep column values updated (e.g., when moving a point or creating a new one), you might find the [AutoFields plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, several things are not right ;) First, if you want to edit a layer you need to use the `layer.startEditing()` and `layer.commitChanges()` methods.

Then, although you can use the `changeAttributeValues` method with a `QgsChangedAttributesMap` parameter, it is more simple to use directly the `changeAttributeValue` method on the layer since you already wrote a `for` loop:

```
colIdx = layer.fieldNameIndex('Coord_X')

layer.startEditing()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    x = geom.asPoint().x()
    layer.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), colIdx, x)
layer.commitChanges()
```